# Formateo de resultado en SQL mostrar '000025' en lugar de 25

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

```
ID          MONTH
21714       JAN
76101       JAN
175187      FEB
243575      APR
299116      JUN
304742      JUN
```

Necesito genera una cadena de 14 caracteres por cada registro similar a `'ABC00000000000'`, mezclando el `mes` y el `id`, y colocando `0`'s entre ellos:

```
ID          MONTH   ALIAS
21714       JAN     JAN00000021714
76101       JAN     JAN00000076101
119024      JAN     JAN00000119024
175187      FEB     FEB00000175187
243575      APR     APR00000243575
299116      JUN     JUN00000299116
304742      JUN     JUN00000304742
```

Comment: Select 
  ID,MONTH, MONTH + RIGHT('00000000000'+Ltrim(Rtrim(ID)), 11) AS 'Alias' 
from TABLE

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza lo siguiente:

```
SELECT ID, MONTH, MONTH + RIGHT('000000000000000'+ISNULL(ID,''), 14) AS 'Alias'
FROM Tabla
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, el select que me das concatena las dos columnas pero no agrega los 0's para completar los 14 caracteres que necesito. :(

Comment: Que tal, mis disculpas, ya lo he corregido. Como funciona? simple, dentro del Right como primer parametro, le concateno 14 0's, y como segundo le digo que me extraiga 14 caracteres de dicha concatenación desde la derecha. Saludos.

Comment: Rostan, muchas gracias, me dejaste cerca de la respuesta y pude encontrar lo que buscaba.

Select 
  ID, MONTH, MONTH + RIGHT('00000000000'+Ltrim(Rtrim(ID)), 11) AS 'Alias' 
from TABLE

con esta consulta tengo el 'Alias' que necesito. solo fue cambiar el 'ISNULL' por un Ltrim(Rtrim())

Comment: Bien por ti @ProMas, un gusto haberte ayudado. Por favor marca la respuesta como válida para que se cierre la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: También se podría usar un `REPLICATE('0',14)` en lugar de escribir los catorce ceros. (Útil en caso de que se quiera generar la consulta por código)

Comment: Es válido @LogoS, buen aporte.